# How to save output when running job on cluster using SLURM

Tags: r, slurm

I want to run an R script using SLURM. I have created the R script, "test.R" as shown:

```
print("Running the test script")
write.csv(head(mtcars), "mtcars_data_test.csv")
```

I created a bash script to run this R script "submit.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash

#sbatch --job-name=test.job
#sbatch --output=.out/abc.out
Rscript  /home/abc/job_sub_test/test.R
```

And I submitted the job on the cluster

```
sbatch submit.sh
```

I am not sure where my output is saved. I looked in the home directory but no output file.

**Edit**

I also set my working directory in `test.R`, but nothing different.

```
setwd("/home/abc")
print("Running the test script")
write.csv(head(mtcars), "mtcars_data_test.csv")
```

When I run the script **without SLURM** `Rscript test.R`, it worked fine and saved the output according to the set path.

Comment: @d.b, I set my directory `setwd("/home/abc")` in `test.R`, but nothing different.

Comment: yeah that's one way.. but if there's different /home/, it would crash because there's no /home/abc/. The other thing that comes to my mind is you need to load the module R ?

Comment: Are you sure the `write.csv()` command is being executed at all?

Comment: @StupidWolf, Thanks, I have set the correct path, "/abc" is a dummy.

Comment: @Dunois, Yes I am sure, please see my edit.

Comment: If you have to add a module, it goes into the bash script (`module load yadayada`).

Comment: @Dunois, Thanks, let me try this

Comment: In the rather odd scenario that Slurm is redirecting your bash script to execute in (or output to) some random directory, you could try adding a `cd /path/to/mydir` before `Rscript /path/to/myscript.R`. I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with the R and bash scripts you posted here. I tried them on Slurm, and they work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Slurm will set the job working directory to the directory which was the working directory when the `sbatch` command was issued.

Assuming the `/home` directory is mounted on all compute nodes, you can change explicitly the working directory with `cd` in the submission script, or `setwd()` in the R syntax. But that should not be necessary.

Three possibilities:

- either the job did not start at all because of a configuration or hardware issue ; that you can find out with the `sacct` command, looking at the `state` column.
- either the file was indeed created but on the compute node on a filesystem that is not shared; in that case the best option is to SSH to the compute node (which you can find out with `sacct`) and look for the file there; or
- the script crashed and the file was not created at all, in that case you should look into the output file of the job (`.out/abc.out`). Beware that the `.out` directory must be present before the job starts, and that, as it starts with a `.`,  it will be a hidden file, revealed in `ls` only with the `-a` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The --output argument to sbatch is relative to the folder you submitted the job from.  setwd inside the R script wouldn't affect it, because Slurm has already parsed that argument and started piping output to the file by the time the R script is running.

First, if you want the output to go to /home/abc/.out/ make sure you're in your homedir when you submit the script, or specify the full path to the --output argument.

Second, the .out folder has to exist; I tested this and Slurm does not create it if it doesn't.